# Words in text counter

Tags: python, python-3.x

This accepts text and returns a list of all words which occur with a required frequency (default frequency is 2). It works well, but gets too slow with large texts, more than 1M words. Where can this function be improved to speed searches in larger text?

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def words_in_text_counter(in_text,frequency=2):
    no_noise_text = re.sub(r'[0-9.,:;<>"#!%&/()=?*-+]','',in_text.lower()).strip().split()
    frequency_dict = {}
    for key, value in Counter(no_noise_text).items():
        frequency_dict.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
    try:
        print(str(frequency)+' times words in text.')
        return frequency_dict[frequency]
    except KeyError:
        return str(frequency)+' times never happens in text.'
```

Comment: Do you want the full frequency_dict returned, or only those word with a given frequency, or above a given frequency? Kind of doesn't make sense to just return the words at a given frequency, and then having to rerun a second time if you want to check for another frequency...

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is ultimately:

```
no_noise_text = re.sub(r'[0-9.,:;<>"#!%&/()=?*-+]','',in_text.lower()).strip().split()
```

There's a lot to dislike about this line. It horribly violates the Law of Demeter. It takes a while to figure out what it is supposed to do. It uses the wrong tool for the job. And it's inefficient.

First, to start with, if the goal is to split a strict by non-alpha characters, then we should just use the correct function: [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
words = re.split("[^a-z']+", in_text.lower())
counts = Counter(words)
```

Next, this is going to be inefficient. We have to walk the *entire* string once (to make it lower-case), then *again* to split it. And then we have to keep all of the words in memory. We don't have to do any of that if we **really** start with the correct function: [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
re.finditer("([a-zA-Z']+)", in_text)
```

That will give you an iterator over the words. Which you can stick into a generator expression that you can pass to `Counter`:

```
words = re.finditer("([a-zA-Z']+)", in_text)
counts = Counter(m.group(0).lower() for m in words)
```

And if you're already using `Counter`, you may as well use `defaultdict`:

```
freq_dict = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in counts.iteritems():
    freq_dict[key].append(val)
```

Note that I'm using `iteritems()` (which just gives you a generator) rather than `items()` (which must give you the full list).

Furthermore, why do we need a `frequency_dict`? We only care about those words which match the given frequency. Why not just keep a list?

```
frequency_list = []
for key, val in counts.iteritems():
    if val == frequency:
        frequency_list.append(key)
```

**Putting it all together**

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def words_in_text_counter(in_text, frequency=2):
    words = re.finditer("([a-zA-Z']+)", in_text)
    counts = Counter(m.group(0).lower() for m in words)

    frequency_list = []
    for key, val in counts.iteritems():
        if val == frequency:
            frequency_list.append(key)

    if frequency_list:
        print(str(frequency)+' times words in text.')
        return frequency_list
    else:
        return str(frequency)+' times never happens in text.'
```

Comment: I'm kind of unsure what the OP really wants, but wouldn't it make more sense to actually return the frequency_dict, and then provide some simpler map function to get either the word list for a given frequency, or frequencies above a given level?

Comment: Thanks Barry it is much faster now. I was unable activate counts.iteritems() because iteritems() method not available in Counter and use items() instead

Comment: `.iteritems()` is only available in Python 2.x; the OP has tagged the question with [tag:python3] which means that `.items()` is fine (and the only approach, afaik)